# Order html table on hidden values

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have a html table which uses the bootstrap table library to sort the data by column values. This works fine if the data is expressed as a float or int, but I have a column of times. I wish to have the times represented by a string in the form % hr & % min, however because they are a string they are not data-sortable. In the example below '15 hours and 2 minutes' is much larger than '32 minutes', however the sort will place '32 minutes' at the top as it begins with a 3.

Is there a way to have the table display my human readable values, while sorting on a different set of hidden data (total minutes)?

To be clear, the table must be interactable, so that the user can choose which columns the data is sorted by.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table"
       class="table-striped"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-sort-name="traveltime"
       data-sort-order="desc">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Distance</th>
            <th data-field="traveltime" data-sortable="true">Travel Time</th>
            <th data-sortable="true">Created Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Name</td>
            <td>15.1</td>
            <td>15 hr & 2 min</td>
            <td>2018-02-11 18:15:15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example Name 2</td>
            <td>10.1</td>
            <td>32 min</td>
            <td>2018-02-11 18:19:05</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: What are you using for sorting? Could you add a data field (eg. `data-sortvalue`) with a minutes or seconds value to the TD element and if present sort by that instead of the contents of the TD?

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap plugin bootstrap-table to handle sorting. I've updated my question with a code snippet showing it in action.

Comment: I've added the tag `bootstrap-table` so maybe someone with knowledge of that can help.

Comment: @JoshKidd, are you open to maintaining the source data for the table in JSON or JavaScript as opposed to in HTML like your example? This will enable you to use bootstrap-table formatter and sorter functions which will get you the result you want. Let me know, happy to answer the question with an example along these lines.

Comment: I was using a jinja2 for loop to fill in the data, in html. If it's easier I can swap to json/javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as per my comment here is an answer based upon the table data as JavaScript (it could equally be a JSON API return).

The table is as per your example with data fields defined in the `<thead>` but:

1. Utilising a Bootstrap Table JavaScript initialisation to inject the table data from an array.
2. Defining a formatter and sorter function for the travel time field.
3. For convenience, I've used the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) library to deal with dates and durations.

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Example Name',
  distance: 15.1,
  travelTime: 15 * 60 + 2, // '15 hr & 2 min',
  created: moment('2018-02-11 18:15:15').toDate(),
}, {
  name: 'Example Name 3',
  distance: 25.1,
  travelTime: 24 * 60 + 2, // '15 hr & 2 min',
  created: moment('2018-02-11 18:25:15').toDate(),
}, {
  name: 'Example Name 2',
  distance: 10.1,
  travelTime: 32, // '32 min',
  created: moment('2018-02-11 18:19:05').toDate(),
}]

function formatTravelTime(value, row, index, field) {
  return moment.duration(value, 'minutes').humanize()
}

// this is not required in the case, but as an example of a sorter
function travelTimeSorter(a, b) {
 return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0)
}

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-field="distance" data-sortable="true">Distance</th>
      <th data-field="travelTime" data-formatter="formatTravelTime" data-sorter="travelTimeSorter" data-sortable="true">Travel Time</th>
      <th data-field="created" data-sortable="true">Created Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```